# Mongoose not throwing E11000 duplicate key error in test

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I have a fairly simple `UserSchema`. I simplified it for better readability

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        }
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

I now want to test if a duplication error is thrown rightfully using `jest`:

```js
it("throws MongoDB duplicate error with code 11000", async () => {
    const user = new User(testUsers.valid);
    const user2 = new User(testUsers.valid); //clone user

    await user.save();
    try {
        await user2.save();
        fail("Should throw error");
    } catch (err) {
        const {name, code} = err;
        validators.validateMongoDuplicationError(name, code);
    }
});
```

We expect that the `await user2.save()` throws an error that we catch - but unfortunately, no error is thrown and jest autofails at `fail()`.

**Despite having name and email set to `unique` Mongo does not throw a duplication error. Why?**

*Additional information:

calling `console.log` after the 2nd user is saved gives us these objects:*

```
//console.log(user)
{
      role: 'user',
      favouriteColor: 'green',
      _id: 60a7da5e7820e323e4bf9a31,
      name: 'Name',
      email: 'name@email.com',
      password: '$2b$10$7ceCGzc8Zo03RK0xAFG50.QSBAAYejXmw6VNmdXhI1fhZNa2fFzn.',
      createdAt: 2021-05-21T16:05:50.051Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-05-21T16:05:50.051Z,
      __v: 0
    }
```

```js
//console.log(user2)
{
      role: 'user',
      favouriteColor: 'green',
      _id: 60a7da5e7820e323e4bf9a32,
      name: 'Name',
      email: 'name@email.com',
      password: '$2b$10$qkB8OL6Rs00XfULT8haBfOKPy.h4hN3s3ZsQwtCeP/OEMYBMNArfa',
      createdAt: 2021-05-21T16:05:50.124Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-05-21T16:05:50.124Z,
      __v: 0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to dropping the DB `afterEach` test, I dropped the `unique` index as well. This caused a race condition between `user.save() / user2.save()` and the index getting generated - `user2.save()` was faster, so it got saved as the `unique` constraint didn't exist yet.

By deleting all users instead of dropping the DB, the index stayed intact and no race condition occured

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar problem.
Resolved it by shutting down the MongoDB server and restarting it.

Comment: I use a MongoDB inmemory server for testing. `beforeAll` I connect to a newly generated DB, `afterEach` the DB is dropped and `afterAll` the DB is stopped again. Just started IDE again - this cannot be it.